# Android device no longer shows in FIles browser

Tags: pantheon-files, files, wine, android

I was installing `wine` (hardest install of my life) and I didn't read the packages that would be deleted/installed/uninstalled thoroughly enough (I was stuck in dependency hell). It destroyed my elementary install. I had to reinstall most of my programs (though configuration still seemed to be there); including `elementary-desktop` and the login client.

There remain many changes to fix (but hey, at least I have wine not working very well now?). One of these is that when I used to plug my Android in it would show up on the Files browser. Now I cannot see it, even though I can see it when I `lsusb`. Does anyone know which file I've broken here?

Thanks!

Comment: I sometimes use `wine` with Playonlinux in elementary OS and it works okay. How did you install `wine` - did you use PPA or something, or just default repos?

Comment: Do you have all the gvfs packages installed? In particular "gvfs-backends".  Try rebooting after installing packages to make sure they take effect.